# angular-i18n how to put the default language when %%KEY_NOT_FOUND%%

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internationalization, angular-i18n

I am working in a project with a tonne of text and translation. My project is code in angularJs and I use angular-i18n. My problem is when I forget to add the key in every json language it is display `%%KEY_NOT_FOUND%%`.

So I would like to know if it is possible to put a default language instead of this ugly message.

Thanks!